# where can i find ServiceAccountCredential

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am working in google api with asp.net c#, My goal is access google api using service account.

I have imported all needed dlls to create [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to access admin features(admin sdk).

But i couldn't find  ServiceAccountCredential.

How can i implement this in my project?

Comment: did  you tried and get  a solution?

Comment: There's definitely some documentation disconnect. I'm trying to figure this out, too. I will try to remember to come back here when I get it figured out.

Answer (score 28):

Here's how you do it in 2017:

- Go to the [Service Accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts)
- Create a private key for the service account as a JSON file
- Put the downloaded file in your project (for development) or bake it in your build process
- Reference the [Google.Apis.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) package in your code

  ```
    using (var stream = new FileStream("key.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                         .CreateScoped(scopes)
                                         .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

        //profit
    }
  ```

Comment: I get "Error creating credential from JSON. Unrecognized credential type ." any idea why?

Comment: I have found a solution for the problem, but it's different from yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905074/google-analytics-embed-api-server-side-authorization-not-rendering-the-charts-wi what do you think about it?

Answer (score 12):

[ServiceAccountCredential](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.0-rc/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1ServiceAccountCredential.html) is part of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2

Simple example using BigQuery:

```
using System;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

//Install-Package Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2
namespace GoogleBigQueryServiceAccount
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("BigQuery API - Service Account");
            Console.WriteLine("==========================");

            String serviceAccountEmail = "539621478854-imkdv94bgujcom228h3ea33kmkoefhil@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.DevstorageReadOnly }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "BigQuery API Sample",
            });


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but where do these parts come from:

new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

Comment: Google Developers console you can download a p12 file or now a json file but that uses different code

Answer (score 1):

I am using Xamarin Studio and I have an NUnit test library project (PCL) working on my Mac using ServiceAccountCredential. I just tried to move it to an Android test project (MonoDroid), and ServiceAccountCredential does not exist. ServiceAccount does exist (its ancestral class). So this problem may be related to the compile target, and ServiceAccountCredential not being implemented for your target.