# Why does ServiceAccountCredential fail with invalid credentials?

Tags: c#, google-compute-engine, google-api-dotnet-client

Based on this prior question:
[where can i find ServiceAccountCredential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883379/where-can-i-find-serviceaccountcredential)

I created my own service account, downloaded the .p12 key, enabled datastore.

But I still get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestErro
r
Invalid Credentials [401]
Errors [
        Message[Invalid Credentials] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[aut
hError] Domain[global]
]

   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\code\google.co
m\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\defa
ult\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 93
   at TestDotNet.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\jeff\rgs\udemy\TestDotN
et\Program.cs:line 42
```

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

// Install-Package Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Http;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2;
using Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace TestDotNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
                @"surferjeffEasyBates-ce8b875830c2.p12",
                "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var serviceAccountEmail = "340967622364-pls45ap9lu4u6ivtivpus62tm8sgtodg@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { DatastoreService.Scope.Datastore }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));
            var service = new DatastoreService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "surferjeffEasyBates",
                HttpClientInitializer = credential, 
            });
            var lookup_body = new LookupRequest()
            {
                Keys = new Key[] { new Key() { Path = new KeyPathElement[] { new KeyPathElement() {
                    Id = 1,
                    Kind = "Thing"
                }}}}
            };
            var lookup = new DatasetsResource.LookupRequest(service, lookup_body, "surferjeff-easybates");
            var response = lookup.Execute();
            var found = response.Found[0];
            var entity = found.Entity;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same error no matter whether I run on a google compute engine instance or my local machine.

Answer (score 3):

You are just missing a required scope for Cloud Datastore.  In addition to the datastore SCOPE, it requires 'userinfo.email'

If you actually want run inside GCE, you can simply use "ComputeCredentials" as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-dotnet-samples).

- remember to set datastore and userinfo scopes while creating the instance

Add a Google Compute Engine instance and start it, following the instructions for starting an instance in the [Google Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#accessing_the_datastore_api_from_a_compute_engine_instance). In addition to the project ID and the instance name, you must also specify both the datastore anduserinfo.email scopes as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication).

The scopes line should be the following :

```
Scopes = new[] { DatastoreService.Scope.Datastore ,"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"}
```